# horizontal number picker with bar chart in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to android and I have stored my data into database.Now I want to retrieve the data and to show it on number picker attached with x axis of a bar chart.There are only code of simply representing the data on a bar chart but it did not help me.